# How to use ChangeDetectionStrategy for data update between parent-child components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, onchange

I have look at several topics related to `ChangeDetectionStrategy` and I am confused with the different usages of it. I simply want to update data in the child component whenever the data is changed on parent component. For this aim, I see that `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is added to the `Component` field of the parent, but I am not sure if I should use `ChangeDetectorRef` parameter or some default methods e.g. `ngDoCheck()` method. So, how can I perform this between parent and child components? And should I explicitly add the parameter that come from parent, or it is automatically update the `@Input` variables?

```
import { Component,
         Input,
         ChangeDetectionStrategy,
         ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data: string[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  refresh() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: "data is changed on parent component". Since data is an array if the reference of that input changes your child component will reflect the changes automatically. Else you have to call `detectChanges` manually.

Answer (score 3):

The difference for the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, your component will only will detect the changes when something like below happens :

1. The Input reference changes
2. An event originated from the component or one of its children
3. Use the async pipe in the view
4. Run change detection explicitly

So if you don't change input's reference you have to detect changes manually.
Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-parent-child-onpush-tqdxy3?file=src/parent/parent.component.html) that shows the difference between `OnPush` and `Default`

Answer (score 0):

With **ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush** your child component will perform update only if data in **@Input** is really updates, so you need your data to be **immutable**, those after updating data Angular will perform ChangeDetector and update components view.

You can check this example: [https://angular-cd-immutable-example.stackblitz.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cd-immutable-example?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: As far as I understood, there is nothing special to be done except from adding `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the child's `@Component` part. `@Input` variables are already defined and will automatically be updated via `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the child's `@Component` part. Is that true?

Comment: In demo link you need to pay attention to the way the data updates for inputs.

I think you need to check some materials on that issue. It may help you better: 

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

https://pascalprecht.github.io/slides/angular-2-change-detection-explained/#/

Comment: OK, changeDetectionStrategy is not about updating the data itself, but is about how your component will react on updates. With default it will perform recalculation on every change no matter which, with OnPush it will perform recalculation only if the input data value or reference to it is really changed. So to perform update between child and parent you can switch to Default strategy or change the reference to an array you provide to child inside parent component.

Comment: And yes you need to explicitly add parameter on childs tag, in your case parent will contain something like this: <app-child [data]="dataFromParent"></app-child>

Comment: But is it not good idea to use changeDetectionStrategy in order to update child component after the data that is passed from parent is changed? I am confused with your previous comment.

Comment: But you update data via properties that are decorated with @Input,  ChangeDetectionStrategy is just tell component how it should behave on updates. By default all components have changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default, so it is already there and it means to perform recalculation on every ChangeDetection circle, with OnPush recalculation will be performed only if reference or value on input changed and after that component will be marked as open for recalculation, changedetection will be started and components view will be updated.

Comment: Then I think I need to use templateRef as I just want to detect the input parameter by using `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. Is that true? If so, Any example please for that in your answer?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by detect the input parameter by using ChangeDetectionStrategy and why you need templateRef? Please look through materials I suggested earlier as it will give you better understanding of Angulars ChangeDetection.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to create a new reference to an array by using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

[A full stackblitz example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-rrzbbr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

app.component.html

```
<button 
     (click)="people.push({firstName: '1', lastName: '1'}); people = people.slice()">
   +</button>
<div>
  <p> {{ people | json }} </p>
</div>
<br/>
<person [persons]="people"></person>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
   people: any[] = [ 
     {
      firstName: "Alex1",
      lastName: "Brown1",
      age: 55,
     },
     {
      firstName: "Foo2",
      lastName: "Bar2",
      age: 44,
     },
    {
      firstName: "Fido3",
      lastName: "Johnson3",
      age: 14,
     }

   ]
}
```

and `person.component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
  Hello I am {{person.firstName}} and I am {{ person.age}}
</div>
```

and person.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, 
    ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';

class test {}
@Component({
  selector: 'person',
  templateUrl: './person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() persons: any;
  
}
```